# Update solo en algunos registros iguales

Tags: oracle, update, toad

Tengo una duda que seguramente un experto responderá facilmente.

Estoy usando Oracle como manejador de base de datos, mi cuestión consiste en como puedo hacer un Update a 3 de los 5 registros que hay una tabla, los cuales tienen todos la misma información en sus columnas.

Como ejemplo de lo que busco hacer es, tengo esta tabla:

NumeroSalida ----- Articulo  -------- NumeroDeSerie

10  ------------------    BateriasRT

10  ------------------      BateriasRT

10      ------------------      BateriasRT

10       ------------------     BateriasRT

10        ------------------    BateriasRT

y lo que busco hacer es que después del Update, quede así:

NumeroSalida ----- Articulo  -------- NumeroDeSerie

10  ------------------    BateriasRT-----------SERIE875

10  ------------------      BateriasRT-----------SERIE8757

10      ------------------      BateriasRT-----------SERIE87667

10       ------------------     BateriasRT

10        ------------------    BateriasRT

Quedo atento a respuesta, Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `rownum` y especificar que sean las tres primeras filas. Algo así:

```
UPDATE tuTabla
  set NumeroDeSerie = 'SERIE875',
WHERE rownum <= 3
```

Comment: Correcto, me funcionó tu respuesta y es justo lo que estaba buscando.